# Symfony: сессии в суб-доменах

Tags: php, cookie, symfony3

Описание: есть несколько веб-сайтов, которые планируется развернуть на разных доменах третьего уровня. При этом только один из них (последний, написанный с использованием фреймворка Symfony) поддерживает авторизацию пользователей. Размещение веб-сайтов на доменах третьего уровня позволяет мне авторизовать пользователей на одном из них (в данном случае portal.example.com), записать сессии и в дальнейшем использовать их в сайтах на других поддоменах (таких как first-app.example.com, например).

---

*Вопрос: только последний веб-сайт написан на Symfony. Остальные были написаные ранее на чистом php. Как с минимальными потерями реализовать в старых приложениях проверку авторизации пользователей?*

---

Если вдруг понадобится: авторизация происходит по логину\паролю, в контексте Symfony - это реалзуется записью токена в сессию (используется класс **UsernamePasswordToken**).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056262/symfony2-transparent-authorization-process-between-subdomains ну и на стороне чистого php надо повторить логику авторизации либо заюзать компонент Symfony Security

Comment: @tcpack4, спасибо за ответ!